# Can I limit the value in an xml tag to some string plus the value of another tag that's in the same node

Tags: xsd

First off, forgive me as I'm entirely new to xml/xsd.
A node in my xml file which looks like this...

```
<root>
  <XmlDetails>
    <XmlName>SomeName</XmlName>
    ....
    <XmlPath>path/SomeName</XmlPath>
    ...
  </XmlDetails>
  <XmlDetails>
    ...
</root
```

Where XmlPath will contain some prolog string (e.g. "path/") followed by that node's XmlName value.
Is there a way to enforce this within an xsd file?

I looked at union but I'm not sure how to get the value of the XmlName element.

```
<xs:element name="XmlPath"
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:union memberTypes="prolog epilog" />
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="prolog">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="path/"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="path2/"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="path3/"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType> 

<xs:??? name="epilog">
  How to get the value of XmlName
</xs:??>
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible within an xsd file?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a rule in XSD based on the content of some other element in the XML file being validated.

The best you can do is to specify a regular expression rule for the content of `XmlPath`, something like:

```
<xs:element name="XmlPath">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="\w+/\w+"/>
    </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

(the content of `XmlPath` must be a word followed by '/' followed by another word....)